# Web Deployment Project failing build (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-deployment-project

I am trying to build a Web Deployment Project in Visual Studio 2008 and it keeps failing and I am not sure why. Error:

```
------ Build started: Project: website_deploy, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
if exist ".\TempBuildDir\" rd /s /q ".\TempBuildDir\"
'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(92,7): error MSB3073: The command "if exist ".\TempBuildDir\" rd /s /q ".\TempBuildDir\"" exited with code 1.
Done building project "website_deploy.wdproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have the same project on another machine and it builds just fine. I have downloaded [Visual Studio 2008 Web Deployment Projects - RTW](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) and installed Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2008.

Edit:

In the error list, it has `Error 1 The command "if exist ".\TempBuildDir\" rd /s /q ".\TempBuildDir\"" exited with code 1.`. I don't know why it is coming up with `C:\Documents` as the project is in a folder without spaces (`C:\Web\Projects\`)

It happens with a brand new web deployment project, created by right-clicking on the website and clicking `Add Web Deployment Project`.

Edit (29 Jan). More verbose output, failes whenever `<exec>` with `if exist` is used:

```
Building with tools version "3.5".
Target "_PrepareForBuild" in file "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets":
  Using "CreateProperty" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
  Task "CreateProperty"
  Done executing task "CreateProperty".
  Task "CreateProperty"
  Done executing task "CreateProperty".
  Task "CreateProperty"
  Done executing task "CreateProperty".
  Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
  Task "Exec"
    Command:
    if exist ".\TempBuildDir\" rd /s /q ".\TempBuildDir\"
    'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(92,7): error MSB3073: The command "if exist ".\TempBuildDir\" rd /s /q ".\TempBuildDir\"" exited with code 1.
  Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED.
Done building target "_PrepareForBuild" in project "website_deploy.wdproj" -- FAILED
```

Comment: looks like it doesnt like the space in your C:\Documents and Settings

Comment: `C:\Documents` isn't referred to anywhere in the solution or project files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the problem was.

The user profile folder had an @ sign in it, which looks like it may break MSBuild (since @ has a special meaning to MSBuild).

The user profile folder was `C:\Documents and Settings\username@domain`, renaming it to `C:\Documents and Settings\username` fixed this issue I was having. So having spaces in the folder name was not the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 2):

Look here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/9c14fd1c-4c6c-4a5b-ac2a-05a2972036e9

If that doesn't do the trick, search Google for "MSB3073" the specific error code from your post.

Good Luck!

Comment: Nothing on their seems to help as it is a file that is generated by Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

I think your project build to a temp directory, after which it is copied to a more permanent location. `".\TempBuildDir\"` is a relative path which may lead to a non-spaced directory on the pc for which the build succeeds, but fails on your pc because of the location of your temp directory (default in C:\Documents and Settings).

Just to be sure: check the location of the temp directories on your pc and the other machine. Or, if possible, change the TempBuildDir path to something more absolute like C:\Temp or whatever suits you.

To be more specific: if the other machine is a Vista or Win7 pc, the TempBuildDir might reside somewhere within the C:\Users directory. If your machine is a WinXP pc, TempBuildDir most likely resides somewhere in C:\Documents and Settings.